# How to validate pre populated input field with jQuery validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form with fields which are pre populated with data from database, as I need to change phone number according to new data format schema, I also need to immediately fired up validation for pre populate input fieldd.

My JS code is as follows:

Method to validate HR phone numbers according to new schema:

```
$.validator.addMethod("mobileHR", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\(|\)|\s+|-/g, "");
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^\+[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,14}$/);
}, "Unesite broj u fromatu: +385.111234567");
```

And function calls:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // initialize validation
    $('.form-horizontal').validate({ 
        // set immediate validation, on event code 9
        onkeyup: function (element, event) {
            if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
                return;
            } else {
                this.element(element);
            }
        },
        rules: {
            "contactdetails[Registrant][Phone]": {
                required: true,
                mobileHR: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "contactdetails[Registrant][Phone]": {
                required: "Molimo unesite broj telefona"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Input field is like these, and value parameter is allready populated, as data is fetched from database.

```
<div class="controls">
<input kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on" name="contactdetails[Registrant][Phone]" value="011123456" size="30" class="Registrantcustomwhois" type="text">
</div>
```

Now I want to warn a user editing data, even if he doesn't change data in desired input field, to update format of his phone number, so I basically want to call validate() function at the document has been loaded.

Fiddle with example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AlanKis/mxojvbau/2/).

Comment: so you just want to show validation messages on form load ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after putting validation rules, on jQuery's ready, just add `$('.form-horizontal').valid();` to validate form.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxojvbau/3/), updated accordingly